# Maven behavior between projects

Tags: eclipse, maven

- I am using Eclipse IDE.
- I have two maven projects. -Both have MJ icon in package explorer.
- Project A has a pom file, pomA.
- Project B has a pom file, pomB.

I open pomA with Maven POM editor. I click on tab Dependencies. I click Add. I enter a pattern, and results are returned. Yay!

I open pomB with Maven POM editor. I click on tab Dependencies. I click Add. I enter a pattern, and nothing happens. Boo!

What is the configuration *difference between* these projects that cause Eclipse to behave differently? Where should I look to have project B be able to search on Dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the fully evaluated POM with all the parents/dependencies/plugins/properties/etc using **mvn help:effective-pom**

It would be more efficient way

Comment: I added comment. It is more Eclipse IDE. But effective-pom worked well to show some information in IDE as well. I'll update question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh god. New project new index? It came back after letting it sit for seven minutes, literally.

Now response is ok, still slow, but not minutes.